# Angular ng-show variable getting out of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-show

I am trying to build a visual login/logout functionality this way:

1st time when opening the page, the Login link is visible and available, Logout is not. When I do submit Login dissapears and Logout is visible. I tried this with `ng-show` from angular.
The spa page has the common menu:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/public/Register">Register</a></li>
    <li ng-show="loginlogout"><a href="/public/Login">Login</a></li><!--should be true but it is FALSE-->
    <li ng-show="!loginlogout"><a href="/private/Logout">Logout</a></li>
    <li><a href="/private/UserPage">User</a></li>
</ul>
```

For setting the `loginlogout` variable I did it like this:

```
BetAppModule.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.loginlogout = true;

});
```

Although, when I debug in Chrome, `loginlogout` is set correctly to `true`, the desired functionality it is not accomplished. Why is `loginlogout` getting out of scope and it does not stay `true` as it's set in controller.
I also tried using a service. I get the same result.

It works if I use `$rootscope`, but I hear that this is not recommended. Besides, at some point, I get confused with `$rootscope`;

Anyhow I would be grateful getting some help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you wire up a fiddle so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Can you create a jsbin for us

Comment: is your <ul> inside some other directive? in that case, angular might have created a child scope for your variable. use an object to wrap the variable. eg - 
`$scope.myvar.loginlogout = true;`
`<li ng-show="myvar.loginlogout">something</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be a scope issue, I guess you are missing ng-controller="HomeController" on your html (view).

Comment: I don't know what to say about that, because the controller it is set on BettAppModule.config....and it gets there when debugging(or maybe I get it wrong), on home controller.... Maybe I will stick with $rootScope afterall.... Or I will test more, to see if HomeController indeed works as it should...

Comment: If issue still sicks around, create a plunker or fiddle with your problem, so that i can help you on it

Comment: I managed to solve it by explicitly specifying  a common controller on the page( kind of the idea of a $rootscope), inherited by Login,Logout,User,Register controllers(specifyed by .config for every route). On this common controller I set $scope.loginlogout and used it on child controllers. Anyhow, u pointed out that there was a problem with my controller so I looked around it.